# How do I record that this ionic checkbox has been checked by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am trying to record that the user has checked the checkbox, and am not sure where to start. this is using the ionic framework with vanilla JS.

I have the tag for a checkbox:

```
<ion-list>
       <ion-checkbox id="Email-check">Email</ion-checkbox>
<ion-list>
```

A variable that is refering to the ID in the tag:

`const emailCheckbox = this.querySelector('#Email-check');` 
And an empty function:

```
function storeemailCheck(){
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v8/api/checkbox#checked) there is a checked attribute on the ion-checkbox element, so you should be able to target that attribute using `emailCheckbox.checked` inside your function.

```
function storeemailCheck(){
    const emailCheckbox = this.querySelector('#Email-check');
    if (emailCheckbox.checked){
        // do something here..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel Template Driven forms.

```
<ion-checkbox slot="end" color="primary" [(ngModel)]="emailCheckbox" (ngModelChange)="someFunctionnInTs()"  ></ion-checkbox>
```

**emailCheckbox** will be **true** if user checks the checkbox and  **false** if unchecked.If you need a change event you can call `ngModelChange`